# Cannot make vlc from source: libssh error

Tags: debian, sftp, vlc

I tried to install `vlc-2.1.5` from source code using following configure command.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/ --disable-vlc --disable-lua --disable-mad --disable-swscale --disable-postproc --disable-xcb --disable-alsa
```

Configure is perfectly executed with no errors. But when I try to `make`, I encounter these errors.

```
make[5]: Entering directory `/usr/src/vlc-2.1.5/modules/access'
CC       libaccess_sftp_plugin_la-sftp.lo
sftp.c: In function �Open�:
sftp.c:152:15: error: �LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN� undeclared (first use in this function)
sftp.c:152:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
sftp.c:161:5: error: implicit declaration of function �libssh2_session_set_blocking� [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
sftp.c:164:5: error: unknown type name �LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOSTS
sftp.c:164:5: error: implicit declaration of function �libssh2_knownhost_init� [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
sftp.c:164:42: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
sftp.c:172:9: error: implicit declaration of function �libssh2_knownhost_readfile� [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
sftp.c:173:17: error: �LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_FILE_OPENSSH� undeclared (first use in this function)
sftp.c:178:5: error: implicit declaration of function �libssh2_session_hostkey� [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
sftp.c:178:31: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
sftp.c:180:5: error: implicit declaration of function �libssh2_knownhost_check� [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
sftp.c:182:42: error: �LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_TYPE_PLAIN� undeclared (first use in this function)
sftp.c:183:42: error: �LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_KEYENC_RAW� undeclared (first use in this function)
sftp.c:186:5: error: implicit declaration of function �libssh2_knownhost_free� [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
sftp.c:191:10: error: �LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_CHECK_FAILURE� undeclared (first use in this function)
sftp.c:192:10: error: �LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_CHECK_NOTFOUND� undeclared (first use in this function)
sftp.c:195:10: error: �LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_CHECK_MATCH� undeclared (first use in this function)
sftp.c:198:10: error: �LIBSSH2_KNOWNHOST_CHECK_MISMATCH� undeclared (first use in this function)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[5]: *** [libaccess_sftp_plugin_la-sftp.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/vlc-2.1.5/modules/access'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/vlc-2.1.5/modules/access'
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/vlc-2.1.5/modules/access'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/vlc-2.1.5/modules'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/vlc-2.1.5'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Then I tried [this link](https://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc-commits/2011-April/006419.html), but again the same error appears.

My OS distribution is Debian 7.5. What should I do to make errors disappear?

Answer (score 1):

All these undefined symbols (`LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN`, ...) belong to [`libssh2`](http://www.libssh2.org/). You need to install that library in order to compile VLC. For some reason, the `./configure` script did not warn you about it...

You can download `libssh2` from its website or, preferably, use your package manager to do so. For example, with `apt-get`...

```
$ sudo apt-get install libssh2-1 libssh2-1-dev
```

If you compile it manually, you may run into other dependencies which you'll have to install. The `configure` script should tell you about it.

Now, another solution might be to simply disable SFTP support from VLC:

```
./configure --disable-sftp --prefix=/usr/ --disable-vlc --disable-lua --disable-mad --disable-swscale --disable-postproc --disable-xcb --disable-alsa
```

As a side note, keep in mind that disabling features *isn't the actual solution to dependency problems*... Eventually, you'll have to handle them (or use a package manager, which in this case, is clearly the most appropriate solution).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Though  libssh2-1 libssh2-1-dev were installed on my system but disabling SFTP actually worked.